# Two components get called when page refreshes and the state is altered React

Tags: reactjs

Basically, I have one component, let's call it `component1` and a second component, which has been created by duplicating the first one called `component2`. I had to duplicate it, because some objects inside it had to be altered before sending them to the further components.

On one page I have an `onClick` event which triggers `component1` which opens a modal and on another page, `component2` is trigger the same as for the first one.

The problem occurs here, if I'm on the second page where the modal from `component2` is opened and I refresh the page, both components are called, of course `component1` is the first one called and the state is altered by this component which makes me not having the desired information in the second component.

As far as I understood, because of the fact that in both components, `mapStateToProps` is altering my state, both components are called. Not really sure though that I understood right.

Here is my `component1` summary:

```
class LivePlayerModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.highlightsUpdated = null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const queryParam = UrlHelper.getParamFromLocation(IS_QUALIFICATION, window.location);

        if (queryParam === null) {
            ScoringLoader.subscribe(endpointNames.LIVE_SCANNER);
            ScoringLoader.subscribe(endpointNames.PLAYERS);
            ScoringLoader.subscribe(endpointNames.LEADERBOARD);
            ScoringLoader.subscribe(endpointNames.COURSE);
            ScoringLoader.subscribe(endpointNames.STATISTICS);
        }
        //TODO: make fixed fetch on timeout
        this.fetchHighlights();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.playerId !== this.props.playerId) {
            this.highlightsUpdated = null;
        }
        this.fetchHighlights();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        ScoringLoader.unsubscribe(endpointNames.LIVE_SCANNER);
        ScoringLoader.unsubscribe(endpointNames.PLAYERS);
        ScoringLoader.unsubscribe(endpointNames.LEADERBOARD);
        ScoringLoader.unsubscribe(endpointNames.COURSE);
        ScoringLoader.unsubscribe(endpointNames.STATISTICS);
    }

    render() {
        const {
            isOpen, scoringPlayer, isQualification, ...rest
        } = this.props;
        const highlightGroups = getHighlights(this.getCloudHighlights());

        if (isQualification) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <ReactModal isOpen={isOpen} onCloseCb={this.hide}>
                <div className="live-player">
                    {
                        scoringPlayer === undefined &&
                        <BlockPlaceholder minHeight={400}>
                            <BlockSpinner />
                        </BlockPlaceholder>
                    }
                    {
                        scoringPlayer === null &&
                        <LivePreMessage
                            model={{
                                title: '',
                                body: 'Player data coming soon'
                            }}
                            bemList={[bemClasses.LIGHT]}
                        />
                    }
                    {
                        scoringPlayer &&
                        <LivePlayerLayout
                            {...rest}
                            scoringPlayer={scoringPlayer}
                            highlightGroups={highlightGroups}
                        />
                    }
                </div>
            </ReactModal>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    const isQualification = state.scoring.isQualification;
    const { playerId } = ownProps;
    const sitecorePlayers = state.scoring[endpointNames.PLAYERS];
    const scoringLeaderboard = state.scoring[endpointNames.LEADERBOARD];

    const getScoringPlayer = () => {
      
    };

    return ({
        isQualification,
        liveScanner: state.scoring[endpointNames.LIVE_SCANNER],
        scoringLeaderboard,
        scoringPlayer: getScoringPlayer(),
        scoringStats: state.scoring[endpointNames.STATISTICS],
        scoringCourse: state.scoring[endpointNames.COURSE],
        sitecorePlayers: state.scoring[endpointNames.PLAYERS],
        cloudMatrix: state.cloudMatrix
    });
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    fetchPlayerHighlights: (feedUrl) => dispatch(fetchFeed(feedUrl))
});

const LivePlayerCardContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(LivePlayerModal);

export default LivePlayerCardContainer;
```

Here is my `component2` summary :

```
class QualificationLivePlayerModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.highlightsUpdated = null;
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        return nextProps.isQualification;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        ScoringLoader.subscribe(endpointNames.SUMMARY_FINAL);
        ScoringLoader.subscribe(endpointNames.SUMMARY_REGIONAL);
        ScoringLoader.subscribe(endpointNames.LIVE_SCANNER);
        ScoringLoader.subscribe(endpointNames.PLAYERS);
        ScoringLoader.subscribe(endpointNames.COURSE);
        ScoringLoader.unsubscribe(endpointNames.LEADERBOARD);
        ScoringLoader.unsubscribe(endpointNames.STATISTICS);

        //TODO: make fixed fetch on timeout
        this.fetchHighlights();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.playerId !== this.props.playerId) {
            this.highlightsUpdated = null;
        }

        this.fetchHighlights();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        ScoringLoader.unsubscribe(endpointNames.SUMMARY_FINAL);
        ScoringLoader.unsubscribe(endpointNames.SUMMARY_REGIONAL);
        ScoringLoader.unsubscribe(endpointNames.COURSE);
        ScoringLoader.unsubscribe(endpointNames.LEADERBOARD);
        ScoringLoader.unsubscribe(endpointNames.STATISTICS);
    }
  
    render() {
        const {
            scoringPlayer, summaryFinal, ...rest
        } = this.props;
        const highlightGroups = getHighlights(this.getCloudHighlights());

        const queryParam = UrlHelper.getParamFromLocation(IS_QUALIFICATION, window.location);
        const open = (queryParam === 'true');

        if (scoringPlayer !== undefined && scoringPlayer !== null) scoringPlayer.id = scoringPlayer.entryId;

        return (
            <ReactModal isOpen={open} onCloseCb={this.hide}>
                <div className="qual-live-player">
                    {
                        scoringPlayer === undefined &&
                        <BlockPlaceholder minHeight={400}>
                            <BlockSpinner />
                        </BlockPlaceholder>
                    }
                    {
                        scoringPlayer === null &&
                        <LivePreMessage
                            model={{
                                title: '',
                                body: 'Player data coming soon'
                            }}
                            bemList={[bemClasses.LIGHT]}
                        />
                    }
                    {
                        scoringPlayer &&
                        <LivePlayerLayout
                            {...rest}
                            scoringPlayer={scoringPlayer}
                            highlightGroups={highlightGroups}
                        />
                    }
                </div>
            </ReactModal>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    const isQualification = state.scoring.isQualification;
    const { playerId, location } = ownProps;
    const locationIdFromQueryParam = UrlHelper.getParamFromLocation(LOCATION_ID, window.location);
    const locationId = location !== null ? location.locationId : locationIdFromQueryParam;
    const sitecorePlayers = state.scoring[endpointNames.PLAYERS];
    const summaryRegional = state.scoring[endpointNames.SUMMARY_REGIONAL];
    const summaryFinal = state.scoring[endpointNames.SUMMARY_FINAL];
    const scoringLeaderboard = getLeaderboardBasedOnLocation(locationId, summaryFinal, summaryRegional);
    const currentRound = getCurrentRound(locationId, summaryFinal, summaryRegional);

    const getScoringPlayer = () => {
      
    };
   
    return ({
        isQualification,
        liveScanner: state.scoring[endpointNames.LIVE_SCANNER],
        scoringLeaderboard,
        scoringPlayer: getScoringPlayer(),
        scoringCourse: getScoringCourseFromQualificationFeed(),
        sitecorePlayers: state.scoring[endpointNames.PLAYERS],
        cloudMatrix: state.cloudMatrix,
    });
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    fetchPlayerHighlights: (feedUrl) => dispatch(fetchFeed(feedUrl))
});

const QualificationLivePlayerCardContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(QualificationLivePlayerModal);

export default QualificationLivePlayerCardContainer;
```

Basically, the problem i ve got here, is that in `state.scoring` I do not have the information for the endpoints present in the `return` statement of the `render` method before the page finishes the refresh process, which later on makes my app to break.

Hope I've been clear enough.

Is there a solution for waiting the endpoints to get called or even not loading the first component at all?